# how can i get the content of the url below using HttpURLConnection for my android application

Tags: android, iot, nodemcu

here is url ...
https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=R3LQP7IXIXEQ1OIV&field1=0

Actually..I don't want to get the content of url.
I just want to update the value of field1 to 1 and 0.
If I just type this url in any broswer,my thingspeak data will be update.All I need to do is to write code like typing in any broswer of this url.
In that way I think I can turn on and off my led through android application for my IOT project.I think all I need to do is to make connection between apk and thingspeak from this url.I am new to android studio.I have tried many ways.Help me please.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I use android studio with java

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a HTTP GET method (that is what your browser does).
To answer your question:

```
try {
  // create the HttpURLConnection
  url = new URL(yourUrl);
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  // just want to do an HTTP GET here like your browser would
  connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

  // give it 15 seconds to respond
  connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
  connection.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw e;
} finally {
  connection.disconnect();
}
```

There are better (cleaner) ways to do his, but this should answers your question.

PS: Be aware that in Android you will not be able to do this on the main thread! You should do this in a AsyncTask, AsyncTaskLoader, ...

Comment: You can always upvote and mark this answer as correct ;-)

Comment: I know that I m sorry.It can't be voted.Some error appear.